# Select option display many boxes instead of a single dropdown with the options

Tags: javascript, html

So in my server I have a list of places that I would like to chose in dropdown. So before anything I'm splitting the places because they're stored as a single string:

```
  const where = settings?.places.split(',')
```

This is my first try to show it as dropdown options, the problem is that it displays one option with all the places:

```
        <select>
          <option value={where}> {where}</option>
        </select>
```

The other option shows every option in a different box:

```
        {where?.map((site, index) => {
          return(
            <select key={index}>
            <option value={site}>{site}</option>
            </select>
          )
        })}
```

[image]

Image of reference.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is inside a function component, simply move the `select` tag outside of the map function.

```
return (
  ...
  <select>
    {where?.map((site, index) => {
      return(
        <option key={index} value={site}>{site}</option>
      )
    })}
  </select>
)
```